# Django Intersection on Mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, django

My table with this values:

```
id, product, category
1,     A,       1
2,     B,       1
3,     B,       2
4,     C,       1
5,     C,       2
6,     D,       2
7,     E,       2
8,     E,       3
9,     F,       3
10,    F,       4
```

I need to select only products matching category (1 OR 2) AND category (3 OR 4) in Django. Expected result is only product: E

I have error "intersections are not supported in mysql" How i can achieve this using Q() ?

This query return no result but work.

```
main_query = Q()
main_query &= Q(category__in=[1,2])
main_query &= Q(category__in=[3,4])
models.Table.objects.filter(main_query)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Each record in the table has only one category. That category cannot possibly be in 1 or 2, AND in 3 or 4 at the same time.

Comment: Q() doesn't help you get around the logic issue that a single row in the table cannot match both criteria at the same time. Throwing Q() into the question somewhat obscures your original question about the logic of your query.

Comment: you didn't understand my question.

Comment: @cuscode it took you 40 mins to explain what you want. This is why I downvoted.

Comment: I understand what result you're trying to get. You originally were asking it in terms of pure MySQL, then you changed it to a question about Q() and an error you are getting. That's all new information since the first time you posted the question and had already received several MySQL related answers.

Comment: i'm sorry but before i did't now that intersections doesn't work on mysql and i did looking for basic mysql query in order to translate in django

Comment: What you mean return not result but work?

Comment: query work fine (no errors) but no results!

Comment: My first comment explains why there are no results with that logic (whether you do it with Q() or otherwise). A few solutions in MySQL have been posted which work. But it sounds like now your question is how to solve it specifically by using Q()?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT product
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY product
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN category IN (1,2) THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN category IN (3,4) THEN 1 END) > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option with inline tables.

```
SELECT a.* FROM 
 (SELECT * FROM tab  WHERE category IN (1,2)) AS a,
 (SELECT * FROM tab  WHERE category IN (3,4)) AS b
WHERE a.product = b.product ;
```

Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=901fa75f8545c076eaf7b046e0ddf8a5)

Another option using WITH Clause as following

```
WITH cat_1_2 AS (
  SELECT * FROM tab  WHERE category IN (1,2)
),
cat_3_4 AS (
  SELECT * FROM tab  WHERE category IN (3,4)
)
SELECT a.* FROM cat_1_2 AS a, cat_3_4 AS b
WHERE a.product = b.product ;
```

Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d739d28bb7dd54b86a84d1c49b797d92)

Comment: Still using parts off ANSI SQL standard from year 86 i see, iám talking offcource about comma join syntax which is "superseded" with the `... [INNER|LEFT|RIGHT] JOIN .. ON ...` syntax? Doesn't [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=986481e3637ffcb74d2b1080424bbd96) and [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dc6675bce9e3d86e7fe2be02d533b3b6) look much better?  I hope SQL databases will drop this old comma join syntax support soon.. Still iám going to upvote because the execution off the query is correct to get the expected results.

Comment: Thanks @Raymond Nijland for pointing it out. Need to put some effort from my side to come out of old ways.

Answer (score 1):

The `AND` condition is applied to each single row so you have not the result you expected ..but for select the rows associated to the category you have in IN clause.

You could try using a couple  of inner join on subquery

```
    SELECT t.* 
    FROM table t
    INNER JOIN (SELECT 1  cat
                UNION
                SELECT 2) t1 ON  t1.cat = t.category 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT 3 cat
                UNION
                SELECT 4) t2 ON t2.cat = t.category
```

Answer (score 0):

I learned from @RajmondNijland that `INTERSECT` doesn't exist in MySQL. Thanks him. So, You can use the following query with `IN` operator to link the subquery with the main:

```
SELECT product 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE category IN (1,2) 
   AND product IN ( SELECT product FROM table1 WHERE category IN (3,4) );

product
-------
E
```

Comment: MySQL does not support `INTERSECT` so you will have to simulate it like your link said.

Comment: is not a good idea for my case because i need to add multiple conditions. Not just two. My query need to dynamic and parametric. In particular i need this on django language

Comment: @cuscode you could explain what exactly you want previously.

Comment: the question is the same, but i need to quering in django language skipping the problem of unsupported mysql intersections. I need result E because is the only product tha have categori 1 or 2 AND category 3 or 4. Infact it has cat 2 and 3

Comment: @cuscode I cannot see any explanation in any edits of your question telling that `i need to add multiple conditions. Not just two. My query need to dynamic and parametric.`